# Unable to add MySQL Data Nuget package to ASP Core Project

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to add the MySQL Data Nuget package to my ASP Web Core project, but I get this error:

> One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).

I am using Visual Studio for Mac. Here's the full error log I get:

```
Running non-parallel restore.
Reading project file /Users/dk/Documents/HM/Backend/HMBackend/HMBackend/HMBackend.csproj.
Restoring packages for /Users/dk/Documents/HM/Backend/HMBackend/HMBackend/HMBackend.csproj...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1...
Resolving conflicts for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1...
Scanning packages for runtime.json files...
Merging in runtimes defined in package/Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy 1.1.0.
Merging in runtimes defined in package/Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR 1.1.1.
Merging in runtimes defined in package/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.1.0.
Merging in runtimes defined in package/Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostResolver 1.1.0.
Merging in runtimes defined in package/Microsoft.NETCore.Jit 1.1.1.
Merging in runtimes defined in package/Microsoft.NETCore.Windows.ApiSets 1.0.1.
Merging in runtimes defined in package/Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 1.1.0.
Merging in runtimes defined in package/Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHost 1.1.0.
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win)...
Resolving conflicts for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win)...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x64)...
Resolving conflicts for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x64)...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86)...
Resolving conflicts for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86)...
Checking compatibility of packages on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
Checking compatibility for HMBackend 1.0.0 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
Checking compatibility for MySql.Data 6.9.9 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
Package MySql.Data 6.9.9 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package MySql.Data 6.9.9 supports:
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Checking compatibility for System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo 4.0.0 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).
Checking compatibility for System.Xml.XPath.XDocument 4.0.1 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).
Checking compatibility for runtime.any.System.Reflection.Extensions 4.3.0 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).
Checking compatibility for runtime.any.System.Reflection.Primitives 4.3.0 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHost 1.1.0 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).
Checking compatibility for runtime.win.System.Console 4.3.0 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).
Checking compatibility for runtime.any.System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.3.0 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal 1.1.2 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions 1.1.2 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).
Incompatible packages: 1
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'HMBackend'.
```

**Here's what my .csproj looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
        <Folder Include="DAO\" />
        <Folder Include="Model\" />
        <Folder Include="Helpers\" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.3.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="1.2.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Remove="Model\ResponseCallBack.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the NuGet output:

`Package MySql.Data 6.9.9 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package MySql.Data 6.9.9 supports:
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)`

The MySql.Data NuGet package contains assemblies for .NET 4.0 and 4.5. You cannot use these in a .NET Core 1.1 project.

Options:

1. Find another MySql NuGet package or library that supports .NET Standard, PCL or .NET Core. There is the [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) for example.
2. Change your project to target .NET Core 2.0.

   - The MySql.Data NuGet package would need to be tested to see if it is compatible with .NET Core 2.0. Whilst you can use NuGet packages that target .NET from a .NET Core 2.0 project that does not guarantee the assembly will work, since it may be using some API not supported by .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: The MySqlConnector Nuget worked as a great alternative! Thank you